# My grammar identifies keywords as identifiers

Tags: java, antlr4

Almost every word is recognized as a identifier, and  it doesnt even get to the more complex rules. For an example, 'program'is recognized as a conditition and it doesnt recognize 'integer a,b;' as a Decl_list , just the 'integer' part as a Decl.

Do you guys have any ideia why?

Im using this code for testing:

```
program test1
declare
 integer a, b, c;
 integer result;
begin
 read (a);
 read (c);
 b := 10;
 result := (a * c)/(b + 5) ;
 write(result);
end
```

```
lexer grammar MiniLexer;

Program: 'program' Identifier Body;

Body: ('declare' Decl_list) 'begin' Stmt_list 'end';

Decl_list: Decl ';' (Decl ';')?;

Decl: Type Ident_list;
fragment
Ident_list: (Identifier ','?)*;

Type: 'integer' | 'decimal';

Stmt_list: Stmt ';' ((Stmt ';')*)?;

Stmt: Assign_stmt | If_stmt | While_stmt| Read_stmt | Write_stmt;

Assign_stmt: Identifier ':=' Simple_expr;

If_stmt: 'if' Condition 'then' Stmt_list 'end' | 'if' Condition 'then' Stmt_list 'else' Stmt_list 'end';

Condition: Expression;

For_stmt: 'for' Assign_stmt 'to' Condition 'do' Stmt_list 'end';

While_stmt: 'while' Condition 'do' Stmt_list 'end';

Read_stmt: 'read' '(' Identifier ')';

Write_stmt: 'write' '(' Writable ')';

Writable: Simple_expr | Literal;

Expression: Simple_expr | Simple_expr Relop Simple_expr;

Simple_expr: Term | Term Addop Term| '(' Term ')' ? Term ':' Term;

Term: Factor_a | Factor_a Mulop Factor_a;

Factor_a: Factor | 'not' Factor | '-' Factor;

Factor: Identifier | Constant | '(' Expression ')';

Relop: '=' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<=' | '<>';

Addop: '+' | '-' | 'or';

Mulop: '*' | '/' | 'mod' | 'and';

Shiftop: '<<' | '>>' | '<<<' | '>>>';

COMENTARIO: '%' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {skip();};

WS :   ( ' '| '\t'| '\r'| '\n') {skip();};

Constant: ('0'..'9') (('0'..'9'))*;

Literal: '"' ('\u0000'..'\uFFFE')* '"';

Identifier: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') | ('0'..'9'))*;
```

Do you guys have any ideia why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grammar is a lexer grammar, meaning it produces only tokens. Learn the difference between `lexer`, `parser` and combined grammars here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md

In short, remove the word `lexer` from your grammar and change some rules into parser rules (these start with a lower case letter):

```
grammar Mini;

program: 'program' Identifier body EOF;

body: ('declare' decl_list) 'begin' stmt_list 'end';

decl_list: decl ';' (decl ';')?;

decl: type ident_list;

ident_list: (Identifier ','?)*;

type: 'integer' | 'decimal';

stmt_list: stmt ';' (stmt ';')*;

stmt: assign_stmt | if_stmt | while_stmt| read_stmt | write_stmt | for_stmt;

assign_stmt: Identifier ':=' simple_expr;

if_stmt: 'if' condition 'then' stmt_list 'end' | 'if' condition 'then' stmt_list 'else' stmt_list 'end';

condition: expression;

for_stmt: 'for' assign_stmt 'to' condition 'do' stmt_list 'end';

while_stmt: 'while' condition 'do' stmt_list 'end';

read_stmt: 'read' '(' Identifier ')';

write_stmt: 'write' '(' writable ')';

writable: simple_expr | Literal;

expression: simple_expr | simple_expr Relop simple_expr;

simple_expr: term | term Addop term| '(' term ')' ? term ':' term;

term: factor_a | factor_a Mulop factor_a;

factor_a: factor | 'not' factor | '-' factor;

factor: Identifier | Constant | '(' expression ')';

Relop: '=' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<=' | '<>';

Addop: '+' | '-' | 'or';

Mulop: '*' | '/' | 'mod' | 'and';

Shiftop: '<<' | '>>' | '<<<' | '>>>';

COMENTARIO: '%' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' -> skip;

Constant: ('0'..'9') (('0'..'9'))*;

Literal: '"' ('\u0000'..'\uFFFE')* '"';

Identifier: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') | ('0'..'9'))*;

Space: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Note that `{skip();}` is old v3 syntax, use `-> skip` instead.

And `Constant: ('0'..'9') (('0'..'9'))*;` is also old v3 syntax (although still valid in v4). The preferred way to do it is like this:

```
Constant: [0-9] (([0-9]))*;
```

which can simply be written as:

```
Constant: [0-9]+;
```

Comment: Thank you  very much! Im using antlr4 for a college project, still learning everything from lexers to parsers. This will be of tremendous help!

Comment: One question if I may, do you think that is covenient to declare if/else and do/while/for as separate operators?